# How to test for application exceptions Arquillian, EJB, JUnit

Tags: junit, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I am having problems testing application exceptions thrown within an EJB. I am using JUnit, Arquillian, JBoss. I may have a missunderstanding how EJB's should be programmed/tested. If I need to clarify anything, or give more details, or provide more code, please let me know. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to test for application exceptions in an EJB.

When a runtime exception is thrown within the EJB, the transaction is destroyed, and a TransactionRequiredException is thrown. Any subsequent test (that passes when run as a single test) fails with the following exception:

```
javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:63)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.begin(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:65)
at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.begin(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:142)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.CallableMethodHandler.invoke(CallableMethodHandler.java:51)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
at org.jboss.weldx.transaction.UserTransaction$-294104632$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.begin(UserTransaction$-294104632$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
at com.soccerx.PersistenceTest.beginTransaction(PersistenceTest.java:106)
at com.soccerx.PersistenceTest.tearDown(PersistenceTest.java:115)
at com.soccerx.PersistenceTest.preparePersistenceTest(PersistenceTest.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$StatementLifecycleExecutor.invoke(Arquillian.java:351)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.on(BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:222)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:65)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.jmx.JMXTestRunner.runTestMethodInternal(JMXTestRunner.java:128)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.jmx.JMXTestRunner.runTestMethod(JMXTestRunner.java:107)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.service.ArquillianService$ExtendedJMXTestRunner.runTestMethod(ArquillianService.java:226)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:111)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:45)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:235)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:250)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl$TcclMBeanServer.invoke(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.invoke(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:246)
at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v1.ServerProxy$InvokeHandler.handle(ServerProxy.java:1034)
at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v1.ServerProxy$MessageReciever$1.run(ServerProxy.java:215)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState(BaseTransaction.java:257)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:59)
... 98 more
```

Secondly if I try to assert that the exception thrown is of type TransactionRequiredException, then i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException> but was<java.lang.AssertionError>
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:31)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:226)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:35)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:226)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:65)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.jmx.JMXTestRunner.runTestMethodInternal(JMXTestRunner.java:128)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.jmx.JMXTestRunner.runTestMethod(JMXTestRunner.java:107)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.service.ArquillianService$ExtendedJMXTestRunner.runTestMethod(ArquillianService.java:226)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:111)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:45)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:235)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:250)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl$TcclMBeanServer.invoke(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.invoke(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:246)
at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v1.ServerProxy$InvokeHandler.handle(ServerProxy.java:1034)
at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v1.ServerProxy$MessageReciever$1.run(ServerProxy.java:215)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The important code is below:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

@Inject
protected UserTransaction utx;    

@Before
public void preparePersistenceTest() throws Exception {
    beginTransaction();
}

@After
public void commitTransaction() throws Exception {
    utx.commit();
}

protected void beginTransaction() throws Exception {
    utx.begin();
    em.joinTransaction();
}

@Test(expected=TransactionRequiredException.class)
public void testRetirePlayerOnFutureDateBean() throws Exception {

    // SETUP
    Player player = playerDao.findAll().get(0);

    // TEST - method throws IllegalArgumentException if the date is after today...
    playerBean.retirePlayer(player.getId(), new DateTime().plusDays(1));

    // ASSERT - TransactionRequiredException
}

@Test
public void testSavePlayerProfile() throws Exception {
    // another test using an EJB, which passes if above test is commented out
    // its fails only when the previous test has caused the destruction of the transaction
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting this in the [Arquillian discussion forum](https://community.jboss.org/en/arquillian?view=discussions)? This looks like a bug, and may need to be tracked in JIRA. I dont think you'll get an answer here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Cool no problem. I have posted the same question on the forum you specified. https://community.jboss.org/thread/212082